# Prevent re-render on state update for only one part of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, react-native-maps

I'm using dynamic moving markers in my React-Native application, in order to make the markers move I've got state updates on an interval that re-renders the screen with the new marker positions. I'm also trying to use react-native-maps-directions which uses the google Routes API (which costs money) and I can't allow the routes API to get called twice every second because that seems wasteful (also because I'm poor).

Basically, do you know of a way to keep re-rendering the part that updates marker locations while not re-rendering the routes

Here's my render:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <MapView
            allOfMyProps={blahblahProps}
          >

            //This currently does and should re-render every time because I need them to move
            {this.state.markers[1] !== null &&
              this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
                <MapView.Marker
                  key={index}
                  coordinate={{
                    latitude: marker.coordinate.latitude,
                    longitude: marker.coordinate.longitude,
                  }}
                />
              ))}

            /// This is what renders the route, I want this to not re-render every time state changes
          <MapViewDirections
              origin={origin}
              destination={destination}
              apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY} //configure this right
              strokeWidth={10}
              strokeColor="green"
           />


          </MapView>
    </View>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `MapViewDirections` with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) and use a custom "isEqual" function? Or split out a component to render `MapView.Marker` on it's own interval, isolated from this parent component?

Comment: @DrewReese This wasn't exactly how I fixed it, but if you answer it mentioning shouldComponentUpdate I'll give you credit for it. React.memo and shouldComponentUpdate do basically the same thing anyways

Comment: Ah, right, you're still using a class-based component. No, it seems you resolved this on your own merit, I only provided a hint/suggestion. You can answer your own question, BTW.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your help, if you change your mind I'll mark yours as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new external class-based component and using another shouldComponentUpdate which tests to see if the destination prop updated. If it updated, then re-render the component, if not it'll send back what it already rendered. HUGE thanks to Drew Reese for the hint!

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. Will you be able to share the fix? Thank you for your help if possible.

Comment: no clear answer!